# Jenkins job from another repo to run after successful deployment

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After successfully deploying Github repository X to an AWS EB instance via a Jenkins job, I would like to trigger the UI test suite in Github repository Y via Jenkins.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins can trigger downstream jobs via `Post-build Actions` using **Build Other Projects** or you could use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) if you require to pass arguments to the downstream build(s)